# Debugging server-side rendering with React, Express and Weback

Tags: reactjs, debugging, express, webpack-2, server-side-rendering

I have a React app and while server side rendering I get error that I can't decipher:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at t.default (/code/server.bundle.js:1:239027)
    at /code/node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:306:16
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (/code/node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:75:12)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponentWithoutOwner (/code/node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:305:14)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponent (/code/node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:280:21)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (/code/node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:188:21)
    at Object.mountComponent (/code/node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactReconciler.js:46:35)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (/code/node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactMultiChild.js:238:44)
    at ReactDOMComponent._createContentMarkup (/code/node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMComponent.js:653:32)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountComponent (/code/node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMComponent.js:520:29)
```

I would be great if I get some stack error from source-maps or something.

How can I achieve this?

this is code I use for server-side rendering:

```
const store = configureStore();
const app = express();
app.use(compression());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), {index: false}));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    match({routes: routes(store), location: req.url}, (err, redirect, props) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err.message)
        } else if (redirect) {
            res.redirect(redirect.pathname + redirect.search)
        } else if (props) {
            const appHtml = renderToString(
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <RouterContext store={store} {...props} />
                </Provider>
            );
            res.send(template({
                body: appHtml
            }))
        } else {
            res.status(404).send('Not Found')
        }
    })
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log('Production Express server running at localhost:' + PORT)
});
```

I have configured webpack to generate source-maps for my bundle.js, but they are only working when debugging in browser.

Comment: What i suggest is open the `bundle.js` in your text editor and move to `239027` character. If you are familar with the codebase, then on seeing the bundled code, you should be able to tell which part of the code that comes from. It would help if your code is unmangled.

Comment: As far as debugging is concerned, i presume your `bundle` is minified version. I suggest you to use an unminified `bundle` for developing/debugging purpose. This way the stacktrace would point you to correct line number and opening the bundle.js would show you unminified code which would be easy to read and interpret.

Comment: thanks guys, I will try your suggestions. I actually also managed do debug node server-side rendering with chrome dev tools.

Comment: @Panther your suggestion very much helped, I disabled minification and left only babel for transpiling. When I went to that line I saw a comment from source code and I could quickly find out in which component it happend. Then I used sourcemaps with chrome-node-debugging and I found out original place where error occurs!